# Angular js unbind and bind dynamically not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-bind

I have an 2 inputs with ng-model and two elements binding the two models, I want that when I click on a button it switch the bindings i a way that element 1 binds model 2 and element 2 bind model 1, it work perfectly, but when start changing models if affect the two elements!

to illustrate it i've created a[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VquP7fDADDmkjCNAOEdm) !

How to fix this ?

app.js :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope,$compile) {
  $scope.model1="1";
  $scope.model2="2";

  $('#click').click(function () {

    $('#model1').attr('ng-bind','model2');
    $('#model2').attr('ng-bind','model1'); 
    angular.element($compile( $('#model1'))($scope));
    angular.element($compile( $('#model2'))($scope));
    $scope.$apply();

  });

});
```

Comment: Some problem in your JSFiddle. Could you please update it.

Comment: Yes I have updated but i'm trying to add angular js and jquery to it can you try to do so ?

Comment: @AmarAttilaZz do you want to swapping of variable like this https://jsfiddle.net/yBP5J/29/

Comment: no I want to keep the same value of model, only switch the binding of my 2 elements, thought it work juste by switching their ng-bind attribute

Comment: I have created a new plunker instead of the jsFiddle see the link in my original post

Comment: Try to never use jquery in a non directive part of angular. You should never manipulate the dom in a controller or a service. Never. i'll look futher to provide you a clean solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YLqjcUTPrAS5lwaseAmL?p=preview) example;

Never manipulate DOM directly in a controller. Usually you don't manipulate dom yourself. You use angular directive to do what you want. Keep it mind that if you want to use jQuery, you're probably doing it in a wrong way and that there is a way do to it from angular without calling to jQuery.

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$compile) {


  $scope.name = 'World';

  //input1 and input2 will contain the key of the variable bind to the input.
  $scope.input1 = "value1";
  $scope.input2 = "value2";
  $scope.model = {
     value1 : 1,
     value2 : 2
  }

  // Here is my switch function. I just switch the keys and angular will do the rest.
  $scope.switch = function(){
    var tmp = $scope.input1;
    $scope.input1 = $scope.input2;
    $scope.input2 = tmp;
  }
});
```

HTML

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <!-- Angular provide a directive called ng-click to bind function on clic for the html element -->
    <button ng-click="switch()">switch</button>
    <!-- Here i bind the property of an object. I'll just update the key in input1 to change which property is bind-->
    <input type="text" ng-model="model[input1]" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="model[input2]" />
    <h5 id="model1" ng-bind="model[input1]"></h5>
    <h5 id="model2" ng-bind="model[input2]"></h5>
  </body>
```

Hope it helped you out, if you want further explanation go on.

Comment: @AmarAttilaZz Keep it in mind jQuery = almost never within angular.